# Twig accessing variables that need a variable expansion

Tags: php, twig

I have the following code in a Twig template:

```
       {% macro option_display(type) -%}
    {% if server.options_array.options.{{type}}.name is defined %}
        {{server.options_array.options.{{type}}.name}} +${{server.options_array.options.~type~.price}}
    {%else%}
        None
    {% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Twig_Error_Syntax: Expected name or number

How should I get it to expand the variable 'type' in that context? I've tried using `~type~` as well (`concat`).

would be something like `$server['options_array']['options'][$type]['name'];` in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the bracket notation:

```
{% macro option_display(type) -%}
    {% if server.options_array.options[type].name is defined %}
        {{ server.options_array.options[type].name }} +${{ server.options_array.options[type].price }}
    {% else %}
        None
    {% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

You probably want to also check whether `server.options_array.options[type]` is defined before checking whether `server.options_array.options[type].name` is defined.

Furthermore, like the [documentation of the `macro` tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) says, "as with PHP functions, macros don't have access to the current template variables." So you probably need to pass the `server` variable to the macro as well.

So here's a more complete example:

```
{% macro option_display(server, type) -%}
    {% set option = server.options_array.options[type]|default(null) %}
    {% if option.name is defined %}
        {{ option.name }} +${{ option.price }}
    {% else %}
        None
    {% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}

{% from _self import option_display %}

{{ option_display(server, 'foo') }}
{{ option_display(server, 'bar') }}
```

Notice that I'm using a helper variable `option` and the [`default` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html). Without the filter, you'd get a `Twig_Error_Runtime` exception if the `server.options_array.options` array doesn't have the key you are using. (Whether you get this exception or not depends on the value of the [environment option](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options) `strict_variables`.)

[See TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/3szb6a)